# Is there any way to embed a react web application within Outlook as an Add-in without using Yeoman generator

Tags: reactjs, outlook, manifest, add-in

I am trying to embed a web react app in office 365 Outlook as a task pane Add-in without using Yeoman generator.

I built an empty React app (https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app#readme) and I downloaded a default mail manifest file (.xml) from the Office JS site(can see below). I can successfully sideload itas a custom Add-in and it successfully displayed on the ribbon, but when I try to display it as a task pane. It threw this error:

*ADD-IN ERROR: We can't open this add-in from localhost*

I have tried the solution here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/office-suite-issues/cannot-open-add-in-from-localhost
to add a local loopback exemption, but it still doesn't work.

I am not sure what the problem exactly is. I tried many different manifest files and this is one of them:
The default mail manifest file (.xml) from Office JS site:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OfficeApp xmlns=
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:type="MailApp">
  <!--IMPORTANT! Id must be unique for each add-in. If you copy this manifest ensure that you change this id to your own GUID. -->
  <Id>971E76EF-D73E-567F-ADAE-5A76B39052CF</Id>
  <Version>1.0</Version>
  <ProviderName>Microsoft</ProviderName>
  <DefaultLocale>en-us</DefaultLocale>
  <DisplayName DefaultValue="YouTube"/>
  <Description DefaultValue=
    "Watch YouTube videos referenced in the e-mails you  
    receive without leaving your email client.">
    <Override Locale="fr-fr" Value="Visualisez les vidéos
      YouTube références dans vos courriers électronique
      directement depuis Outlook."/>
  </Description>
  <!-- Change the following lines to specify    -->
  <!-- the web server that hosts the icon files. -->
  <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://contoso.com/assets/icon-64.png" />
  <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://contoso.com/assets/hi-res-icon.png" />
  <SupportUrl DefaultValue="[Insert the URL of a page that provides support information for the app]" />
  <Hosts>
    <Host Name="Mailbox" />
  </Hosts>
  <Requirements>
    <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="Mailbox" />
    </Sets>
  </Requirements>

  <FormSettings>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <!-- Change the following line to specify     -->
        <!-- the web server that hosts the HTML file. -->
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue=
          "https://webserver/YouTube/YouTube_read_desktop.htm" />
        <RequestedHeight>216</RequestedHeight>
      </DesktopSettings>
      <TabletSettings>
        <!-- Change the following line to specify     -->
        <!-- the web server that hosts the HTML file. -->
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue=
          "https://webserver/YouTube/YouTube_read_tablet.htm" />
        <RequestedHeight>216</RequestedHeight>
      </TabletSettings>
    </Form>
    <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
      <DesktopSettings>
        <!-- Change the following line to specify     -->
        <!-- the web server that hosts the HTML file. -->
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue=
          "https://webserver/YouTube/YouTube_compose_desktop.htm" />
      </DesktopSettings>
      <TabletSettings>
        <!-- Change the following line to specify     -->
        <!-- the web server that hosts the HTML file. -->
        <SourceLocation DefaultValue=
          "https://webserver/YouTube/YouTube_compose_tablet.htm" />
      </TabletSettings>
    </Form>
  </FormSettings>

  <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
  <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
    <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="And">
      <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
        <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read" />
        <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read" />
      </Rule>
      <Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch"
        PropertyName="BodyAsPlaintext" RegExName="VideoURL"
        RegExValue=
        "http://(((www\.)?youtube\.com/watch\?v=)|
        (youtu\.be/))[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{11}" />
    </Rule>
    <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
      <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit" />
      <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit" />
    </Rule>
  </Rule>
</OfficeApp>
```